# Can't find config.xml anywhere within Jenkins folder

Tags: java, xml, windows, jenkins, file-location

I have downloaded and installed Tomcat servlet on my Windows 8...

Inside which many application's `.war` files are present. Also Jenkins. I was able to start it and create jobs and plugins through it. But I gave a wrong credentials for *Advanced -> plugin -> HTTP Proxy* while installing Maven. Maybe this is what is blocking me to login and gives message: Admin Is Missing the Overall/Read Permission.

I searched in Jenkins and many other sites; hey had mentioned to follow these steps...

1. Stop Jenkins (the easiest way to do this is to kill the servlet container.)
2. Go to `$JENKINS_HOME` in the file system and find config.xml file.
3. Open this file in the editor.
4. Look for the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` element in this file and replace `true` with `false`
5. Remove the elements `authorizationStrategy` and `securityRealm`.
6. Start Jenkins

But I searched everywhere to find the `config.xml` on Windows, but I can't find it. Where it is?

Comment: Maybe your config files is in a system folder like: C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.jenkins. Try to change your Windows explorer settings to view these folders.

Comment: By default Jenkins uses ~/.jenkins directory as JENKINS_HOME. In your case please open home directory of user which runs Jenkins and find .jenkins folder. It should be C:\Users\USER_NAME\.jenkins. Please refer following link for more information https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm locked out of jenkins and I even can't reinstall it because the old settings remain

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 7 I've had the same problem and after looking I found that the config file is in two different folders:

- `C:\Users\user name\\.jenkins`
- `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\\.jenkins`

changing the first one didn't do much, but deleting the second did the job.

Answer (score 3):

By default Jenkins home directory (`JENKINS_HOME`) is set to `~/.jenkins`, this is the location where you can find your Jenkins XML config file.

On Windows your user home directory is under `C:\Users\USERNAME` (equivalent to `%HOME%`). This folder may be hidden (since it has dot in it), so when browsing the files, make sure your program shows hidden files or type the direct path in your *Path/Address* bar.

Here is the brief structure of XML files within Jenkins home folder:

```
JENKINS_HOME
 +- config.xml     (jenkins root configuration)
 +- *.xml          (other site-wide configuration files)
 +- jobs
     +- [JOBNAME]      (sub directory for each job)
         +- config.xml     (job configuration file)
```

See: [Administering Jenkins - `JENKINS_HOME` directory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins)

Answer (score 3):

you could found it under :

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins
```

FYI : you could check your `"JENKINS_HOME"` under `C:\Program Files\Jenkins` inside the file jenkins.xml you will find the path

Comment: Thank you, Mine was the same.

```<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%ProgramData%\Jenkins\.jenkins"/>```

Answer (score 2):

It's not depend on Win OS or Environment variables (I.e - %HOME% OR JENKINS_HOME)

You can find the *confing.xml* file where it's installed. It can be in one of the following paths:

- C:\Program Files\Jenkins
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkis

Answer (score 2):

on windows, it can be found here

c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins

Answer (score 1):

Right now I was facing this issue, after trying multiple solutions. The best solution is to simply paste this path on explorer

"C:\ProgramData\Jenkins"

Note: Usually program data is hidden folder, that's why it will not be visible, so you need to type the path

Answer (score 0):

If not done, try defining JENKINS_HOME  in setclasspath.sh. bounce tomcat, config.xml will be in you JENKINS_HOME.