# Jenkins keeps settings after reinstallation

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, config, tomcat8

I've installed the jenkins.war in my Tomcat 8.

After installation I set that only registered users are allowed to create new jobs, but I have never created any user. Now I can't do anything in jenkins. I'm simply locked-out.

I tried to reinstall it but all the settings remain. I even reinstalled tomcat to get rid of the issue.
I searched my whole filesystem for all files with the name "config.xml" and for everything that has to do with "jenkins", I've scanned the whole Windows-Registry for the key "jenkins".

But nothing helped. My Windows Server can be free of tomcat+jenkins and clean of everything related to it, but as soon as I reinstall tomcat+jenkins the old settings are still present.

Can anyone tell me, where these settings might be?
(obviously not here: [Can't find config.xml anywhere within Jenkins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565275/cant-find-config-xml-anywhere-within-jenkins-folder))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme as you. After a long search i found the config files in two different folders

- C:\Users\user name\.jenkins (obvious)
- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.jenkins : this one by doing a global search on all my files.

I deleted the two folders and i started the tomcat server bingo!!! jenkins returned to his initial state